# Python keeps printing list too many times

Tags: python, printing

How can i make python print only one copy of the illegalstates-list?
It seems to list it for far too long, when all i would require is one copy.

```
import itertools
import copy

BOAT = "B"


def illegalStates(roles):



    allstates = []
    legalstates = []
    illegalstates = []
    husbands = []
    wifes = []
    sisalto = []
    persons = copy.deepcopy(roles)
    persons.remove(BOAT)
    for i in range(1, len(persons)+1):
        els = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(persons, i)]
        allstates.extend(els)
    allstates.append([])

    for state in allstates:
        husbands.append([])
        wifes.append([])
        for henkilo in state:
            if henkilo == "H1":
                husbands[len(sisalto)-1].append(1)
            elif henkilo == "H2":
                husbands[len(sisalto)-1].append(2)
            elif henkilo == "H3":
                husbands[len(sisalto)-1].append(3)
            elif henkilo == "W1":
                wifes[len(sisalto)-1].append(1)
            elif henkilo == "W2":
                wifes[len(sisalto)-1].append(2)
            elif henkilo == "W3":
                wifes[len(sisalto)-1].append(3)
    for i in range(0, len(husbands)):
        if len(husbands[i]) == 0 or len(wifes[i]) == 0:
            legalstates.append(allstates[i])
    print(*legalstates)

    #--------------------------------
    return illegalstates


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Here is the whole code, just in case its some other part of the code that keeps making this happen. 
Also, when that list is printed, it does not print empty slots. Could this be printed somehow?

Comment: You are misunsing list comprehensions for sideeffects - this `[x.sort() for x in state]` is _evil_. Using `for x in state:x.sort()` is better. Beside that: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve]; providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue. Walking through so many lines of code that do _things_ without any prior knowledge is decidedly not fun and the reusability in SO terms is next to zero.

Comment: Still seems to print the list way too many times, thank you for the correction though.

Comment: Way too much code for this kind of question

Comment: @SuperStew I disagree, it looks like we needed to see all of the function calls unless my answer is way off base

Answer (score 0):

Your loop that starts `while len(openlist) > 0:`, contains a call to `legalstates()`, which contains a call to `illegalstates()`, which contains your print statement. Therefore, you're calling the method containing the print every time your `while` loop...loops